# Make a sign in functionality using Riverpod Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

I am new to [river_pod](https://riverpod.dev/) and I won't lie if I said that the documentaion is only for super-senior-engineers

Anyways, I want to implement a `sign in` feature using this package

The logic behind it is simple:- I get the the email and password from the user and then change the `loggedIn` state from being `false` to `true`

Here is my `Provider`

```dart
    final userAuthProvider = StateProvider<Map<String, bool>>(
        (_) => {'signedIn': false, 'loaded': true, 'signInWasDissmised': false});
```

And here is how I use it and change the value

```dart
    void signIn(BuildContext context, String username, String userPassword) {
        // Check if the username/email and password exist and are correct...etc;
        final String usernameOrEmail = username;
        final String password = userPassword;
    
        // ...logic
    
    context.read(userAuthProvider).state['signedIn'] = true;
```

I'm using context.read because I'm inside an `onPressed` of the `RaisedButton`

Now, what's wrong with this is that after changing the value to be `true` I don't get `flutter` to re`build` everything and use the new `variable`

How can I implement such thing? And am I even doing it right?

Comment: No one? Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> context.read(userAuthProvider).state['signedIn'] = true;

You can't do that. Instead, clone the object:

```dart
final auth = context.read(userAuthProvider);

auth.state = {
  ...auth.state,
  'signedIn' = true,
};
```

Comment: There is something wrong... It gives tons of erros remember I'm using the ``StateProvider`` And this is the error that I get:- Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'.
Try adding a selector.dart(missing_assignable_selector)
Expressions can't be used in a map literal.
Try removing the expression or converting it to be a map entry

Comment: Sorry I made a typo